# How to put toolbar on bottom side of the app?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

I tried many. but nothing worked I am using coodinatorlayout.I also used `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
But it is not working well
my app bar_xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.subcategory">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_subcategory" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and activity main  xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but I got this only..[image: but I got this only..]
I want toolbar at bottom..
I tried it in content main .Then its worked but the width of bar does not cover parent width.But I don't need a **padding 0dp** in content main.

my content xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.subcategory"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_subcategory"
    android:background="#ffffff">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is xml of your **content_subcategory** ?

Comment: But some user friendly app uses toolbar at bottom isn't it?? @Tim Castelijns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a suggetion for your issue. I add an AppBarLayout as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

notice: set this AppBarLayout with `layout_gravity="bottom|end"`.
Hope to help you.

Comment: No.when I do thi the current Action bar also moves down..I want two Action bars..One at top and other at bottom.

Comment: @KBJ, my suggestion is that you still keep a toolbar with AppBarLayout layout_gravity="top|start", and add other toolbar with AppBarLayout layout_gravity="bottom|end".

Answer (score 0):

Android design support library has helped to make me to achieve this

To do the same use `BottomNavigationView`
Refer

1. https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

[image: this]